# how do you detect createUpdate() fails?

Tags: sql2o

```
public Connection executeUpdate() {
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

try {
  this.logExecution();
  PreparedStatement statement = this.buildPreparedStatement();
  this.connection.setResult(statement.executeUpdate());
  this.connection.setKeys(this.returnGeneratedKeys ? statement.getGeneratedKeys() : null);
  this.connection.setCanGetKeys(this.returnGeneratedKeys);
} catch (SQLException var7) {
  this.connection.onException();
  throw new Sql2oException("Error in executeUpdate, " + var7.getMessage(), var7);
} finally {
  this.closeConnectionIfNecessary();
}

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.debug("total: {} ms; executed update [{}]", new Object[]{end - start, this.getName() == null ? "No name" : this.getName()});
return this.connection;
}
```

I'm wondering how to test an update failing. The query I'm using is:

```
update my_table set some_field=:some_value
where the_key = :the_key_value
```

And, immediately before `executeUpdate()` runs, I am deleting the record where `the_key == "the_key_value"`.

Does anyone know the correct way to determine if the update failed?

Also, when I go to the [javadoc](http://api.sql2o.org) and click on anything, I get:

> CDN object Not Found - Request ID: c6a9ba5f-f8ea-46ae-bf7a-efc084971878-19055563

Is there a way to build javadoc locally?

EDIT: is the way to check this thru the use of `Connection.getResult()`? Does it return the number of records updated/inserted etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
return connection.getResult() != 0;
```